# How to store parsed date value as date format in mutable array as mutable dictionary in iphone?

Tags: iphone, date, format, xml-parsing

I am new to iphone development .I have parsed a xml page and stored the title, date, summary, in a mutable array "stories" as mutable dictionary "object for key".All the values are saved as string But i want to save the Date value as date format.So that i can sort it with date.How can i achieve that.Please help me out.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an instance of `NSDateFormatter`.
2. Configure the date formatter so that it understands the format you want it to parse (`setDateFormat:`, `setTimeFormat:`).
3. Call the date formatter's `-dateFromString:` method.

Comment: all xml paresed contents are saved by([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
  [currentDate appendString:string];
how should i append?

Comment: You don't change this code. But when the element has been parsed completely, `currentDate`contains the string you then convert to a NSDate with the date formatter.